# Keyboard not working in boot menu

Tags: windows, boot

I am using an Asus P8Z68-M Pro motherboard and a PS/2 Keyboard. My keyboard does not work in boot menus like when I'm selecting an OS and when selecting which kind of Windows safe mode to use. The keyboard works fine at all other times without any problem. The keyboard even works in the ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility.

**Can anybody please guide me to what I can do to solve this issue?**

Oh, and one more thing: I found this neat little trick to bypass this bug, i.e. to keep hitting any of the arrow keys when the computer loads. Then the keyboard works fine for that particular session. But this is not very practical on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: keyboard not working doesn't translate to OS being corrupt, specially at boot menu since there's no OS loaded, yet

Comment: I know. I didn't say it had something to do with the OS.

Comment: If it works in BIOS, fails in low level windows menus, and works again in the actual OS environment, this sounds like a Windows driver problem. Is there something special about the keyboard apart from being PS2? Shot in the dark here, but does it work if you boot with no USB devices connected to the computer?

Comment: Its a modern Logitech Keyboard. I'll try the no-USB thing as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: When I connect only the keyboard and the mouse, it works like a charm. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same problem today, when I was trying to boot from a USB stick and couldn't move around in Boot Menu. It used to work fine with my old keyboard which was connected to a PS/2 port, but for a year now I've been using a new keyboard (Logitech K120) over USB, which won't work by default.

I'll guess you are running on some older BIOS version, which does not have USB keyboard control enabled by default - you need to enable it manually. Newer versions mostly have it enabled by default.

1. Reboot pc.
2. Enter BIOS.
3. *This step may vary in different BIOS versions. In my case the PC had a Gigabyte motherboard*: Select **Interface of Integrated Peripherals** from the main BIOS menu and  locate the **USB Keyboard Support** option and set it to **Enabled** it. In case you use a different BIOS version try to search around - look also for "Legacy USB support" or "Legacy USB keyboard" and similar named options.

[image: BIOS option sample]

4. Save and exist BIOS and try the Boot Menu again.

If the above does not work, you can try plugging the keyboard to other USB ports and see if it get's detected, although it's rarely the case that one of the USB ports is treated as primary (shouldn't be).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I dont have access to the system I used at the time but it was a PS/2 keyboard, not a USB one.

Comment: @Hele yeah - it's an old question and maybe does not solve your problem specifically, but I'm still posting it here since I had to spend quite some time fiddling around with various settings and ideas before I made it work.

Comment: The option can be named slightly differently in some BIOSes. In my case (Abit KN9 mobo, which is ~10y old by now) it is a sub-option of `OnChip USB` named `USB Keyboard Support` and I had to switch it from `OS` to `BIOS` to be able finally choose something different than `Launch Startup Repair` in `Windows Error Recovery` screen for my Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 that didn't restart properly after installing 145 important updates (that was on fresh W7 SP1 installation, in fact 144, because one failed).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I just found a potential solution. Turn off fast boot in the UEFI Settings and your keyboard should work fine. At least that worked for me.